# DNS Problems with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, dns

I have a problem to config the correct DNS. My Server receive over 700K of SMTP request daily which are using DNSBL and in some cases the DNSBL can't handle that amount of mails. I get a  reason: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required back, and the mails go back to sender server. It's just in some cases, when you send one minute later the mail will receive successfully, so it's a problem of an overloaded service.

In this case I made experiences, that the most time the DNS is not working properly.
So I tried to change my DNS over a fix, which I found here. I made a new file on `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/`  for the Google DNS Servers to prevent an overload of the local

```
DNS


    xxx ~ # resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1

Link 2 (enp7s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2
       DNS Servers: 185.12.64.2 185.12.64.1 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2
```

---

Domain is Hoster A ns1.hostera.de
Server is on Hoster B with an A record ns1.hosterb.de
Server use 8.8.8.8 as primary DNS on the Server

I wasn't able to find a way to log this problem, the DNS quests to DNSBL are not listed or where can I create a look of it

Is the config on resolve correct?

Comment: I'm not sure DNSBL is going through systemd-resolved. One thing you could do is increase the cache time (TTL) by replacing it with dnsmasq: https://serverfault.com/a/811541/987638